# Keep same UIViewControllerRepresentable between Swiftui Views without recreating it

Tags: swiftui, uikit, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

Initially I had a swiftui view:

```
MediaPlayerView : View {

   SwiftUIPlayer()

}

struct SwiftUIPlayer: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> MediaPlayerViewController {
```

this worked well. when orientation changes the UIViewControllerRepresentable remains unchanged and keeps playing the video.

i then created a landscape view and potrait view

eg.

```
LandscapeMediaPlayerView : View {
   SwiftUIPlayer()
}

PotraitMediaPlayerView : View {
   SwiftUIPlayer()
}


if isLandscape {
   LandscapeMediaPlayer()
} else {
   PotraitMediaPlayer()
}
```

this now recreates the SwiftUIPlayer and the underlying ViewController and AVPlayerViewcontrollers reset the video.

what is the best/easiest approach here?
it will be a pain to have 1 Mediaplayer view that changes based on a passed in "isLandscape" bool.

having a singleton AVPlayer instance? this caused issues but should I just persevere with that?

Comment: It is likely best to just handle landscape and portrait using auto layout in UIKit, you are recreating the controller every time the Bool changes. SwiftUI likes to maintain ownership of the Views any hacks that take that ownership away will just result in other bugs

Answer (score 1):

You are in luck they added [AnyLayout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/anylayout) in iOS 16 to fix this exact problem!

> Use an AnyLayout instance to enable dynamically changing the type of a layout container without destroying the state of the
> subviews. For example, you can create a layout that changes between
> horizontal and vertical layouts based on the current Dynamic Type
> setting:
>
> ```
> struct DynamicLayoutExample: View {
>     @Environment(\.dynamicTypeSize) var dynamicTypeSize
>
>
>     var body: some View {
>         let layout = dynamicTypeSize <= .medium ?
>             AnyLayout(HStackLayout()) : AnyLayout(VStackLayout())
>
>
>         layout {
>             Text("First label")
>             Text("Second label")
>         }
>     } }
> ```
>
> The types that you use with AnyLayout must conform to the Layout
> protocol. The above example chooses between the HStackLayout and
> VStackLayout types, which are versions of the built-in HStack and
> VStack containers that conform to the protocol. You can also use
> custom layout types that you define.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating an object outside of a SwiftUI view and pass it in?

`ParentView.swift`

```swift
let PortraitView = PortraitView()
let ChildView = ChildView(portraitView: PortraitView)

var body: some View {
   ChildView
}
```

`ChildView.swift`

```swift
struct ChildView: View {
  let portraitView: PortraitView
  var body: some View {
      portraitView
  }
}
```

Comment: this doesnt work for me. it still recreates the view thats passed into the ChildView when changing orientation